# A convex function on an open interval is continuous.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, convex-analysis, lipschitz-functions

I'd like to show that

A convex function defined on open interval is continuous.

I get the result, f is Lipschitz function on any closed subinterval.

But, I am stucked here.

How can i get the result?

Comment: Does this answer your question? : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/941029/is-every-convex-function-on-an-open-interval-continuous

Comment: I have converted "the" into "a" ("the" would mean there is a unique convex function)

Comment: @Kavi Rama Murthy Yes, but i stuck there..

Comment: Cold you tell us where exactly you have problem?

Comment: I want to know the logic, if f is lipschitz on any closed subinterval, then f is continuous on open interval.